# RegEx extract positinal values in simular character group

Tags: javascript, regex

Javascript. I need to extract second **positive** number value in "inset" groups:

Exampple string:

> "box-shadow: inset 3px 4px 0px #444,  inset -1px -2px 0px #444,5px
>   6px 0px #444, inset 1px 1px 0px #444"

so I need to extract **4 and 1** from example string.

don't get how to do this.

Comment: Yes smthing like that .match(/(?!inset )(\d+)(?![px])/g) I'm a stupid in regex, sorry.

Comment: no worries; everybody's a stupid when they try to read regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should do the trick: `/inset -?\d+px (\d+)px/g`

However, as you will need to use the global modifier to catch all the occurrences, you should use the `exec` method in a `while` instead of using `match`, otherwise you won't get the captured groups.

```
var match, regex = /inset -?\d+px (\d+)px/g,
    str = "box-shadow: inset 3px 4px 0px #444, inset -1px -2px 0px #444,5px 6px 0px #444, inset 1px 1px 0px #444";

while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
    console.log(match[1])
}
```

If you want to join the matches in an array, you could use:

```
var matches = [];
while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(matches); // ["4", "1"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/inset\s+-?\d+px\s+\+?(\d+)px/g
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
inset(?:(?: -\d+px)? (\d+)px){2}
```

The result is in the first capturing group.